# pymongo - Как удалить дубли?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

Подскажите, как с помощью pymongo, удалить дубликаты из моей коллекции MongoDB, по ключу.

```
def delete_dupes(key):
    values = []
    for doc in coll.find():
        values.append(doc[key])
    for value in values:
        if len(coll.find({key: value})) > 1:
            do.something
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно попробовать сразу одним запросом запросить данные без дубликатов интересуемого ключа, серьезно сэкономив на обращениях в базу.

Для этого нужно использовать аггрегацию по ключу. А для всех остальных полей брать первое попавшееся значение среди записей с одним и тем же ключом (если это именно то, что тебе надо).

За подробностями могу посоветовать обратиться в официальные доки к mongodb:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/

А ниже - короткий пример, где заполняется база тестовыми данными с дубликатами, а потом применяется описанный в ответе принцип.

```
> use eliminate_dubles
switched to db eliminate_dubles

> db.mycol.insert([{key:1, val:"a"}, {key:1, val:"b"}, {key:2, val:"c"}, {key:3, val:"d"}])
BulkWriteResult({
    "writeErrors" : [ ],
    "writeConcernErrors" : [ ],
    "nInserted" : 4,
    "nUpserted" : 0,
    "nMatched" : 0,
    "nModified" : 0,
    "nRemoved" : 0,
    "upserted" : [ ]
})

> db.mycol.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5df8494444055c6b09dc92dc"), "key" : 1, "val" : "a" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5df8494444055c6b09dc92dd"), "key" : 1, "val" : "b" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5df8494444055c6b09dc92de"), "key" : 2, "val" : "c" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5df8494444055c6b09dc92df"), "key" : 3, "val" : "d" }

> db.mycol.aggregate([{$group: {_id: "$key", val: {$first: "$val"}}}])
{ "_id" : 3, "val" : "d" }
{ "_id" : 1, "val" : "a" }
{ "_id" : 2, "val" : "c" }
>
```

На pymongo переводится элементарно, добавляем кавычки:

```
>>> import pymongo

>>> c = pymongo.MongoClient()

>>> db = c.eliminate_dubles

>>> coll = db.mycol

>>> [a for a in coll.find()]
[{'_id': ObjectId('5df8494444055c6b09dc92dc'), 'key': 1.0, 'val': 'a'}, {'_id': ObjectId('5df8494444055c6b09dc92dd'), 'key': 1.0, 'val': 'b'}, {'_id': ObjectId('5df8494444055c6b09dc92de'), 'key': 2.0, 'val': 'c'}, {'_id': ObjectId('5df8494444055c6b09dc92df'), 'key': 3.0, 'val': 'd'}]

>>> [a for a in coll.aggregate([{"$group": {"_id": "$key", "val": {"$first": "$val"}}}])]
[{'_id': 3.0, 'val': 'd'}, {'_id': 1.0, 'val': 'a'}, {'_id': 2.0, 'val': 'c'}]
```